# Getting "No route matches" when trying to link a stylesheet in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, routes, stylesheet

I’m using Rails 4.2.3.  I created a stylesheets file, “global.css,” which I placed here

```
public/global.css
```

Then I linked to the file in my layout using

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global" %>
```

However, when I view the source of my page, I see

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/stylesheets/global.css" />
```

but clicking on that gives the Rails error

```
No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/global.css"
```

What else do I need to do to get this file included on my page?

**Edit:**  In response to the suggestion given, I moved the file to app/assets/stylesheets, but now when I visit my home page I get the error

```
Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Pages#index
```

and it points to the line

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "global" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rigth place to put custom css is app/assets/stylesheets/

Comment: Hey that didn't work.  I get teh error, "Sprockets::Rails::Helper::AssetNotPrecompiled in Pages#index".

Comment: Try to run rake assets:precompile and then try again.

Comment: That didn't work either, but I ignored a line on the error message screen that read, "Add `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w( global.css )` to `config/initializers/assets.rb` and restart your server".  Doing taht worked after restarting my server.